# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip, get-pip.py

I'm facing an installation issue with pip on CentOS while utilizing Python version 3.10.0. I attempted to install pip by executing the `get-pip.py` script. However, during the process, I encountered errors related to the SSL module, preventing the installation from completing successfully.

To proceed with the installation, I used the following command to retrieve the `get-pip.py` file:

```bash
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/get-pip.py
```

When running the command python `get-pip.py`, I receive the following error:

```bash
[root@env lak]# python get-pip.py
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

How can i fix this issue and install pip on python 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

You're either missing a system SSL library, or the Python installation was built without SSL support.

You can tell which case it is by running `openssl version` and `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"`.

If you're just missing an SSL library, the fix can be as simple as  `yum install openssl`.

If your Python installation doesn't have SSL, then you'll probably have to [build Python from source](https://devguide.python.org/getting-started/setup-building/). Make sure you enable the flag `./configure --with-ssl`.